# How to use Microsoft Graph API version 5.x.x with Dotnet Core API version 6/7/8?

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to use it for Delegated and Application permission. Give me Controller with [Authorized], Programe.cs, Appsettings.json and App Registration Process on Microsoft Azure AD/ Infra.

Just give me example to fetch Me (User) via Web API using delegated/Application token.

I have tried with many times but i got stuck in Authorization DI integration in Programe.cs. Here is my Complete code.

**Nuget Packages I used:**

```cs
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.41.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.55.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.13.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**My Controller:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/v1.0/user")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MasterController> _logger;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        public MasterController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ILogger<MasterController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetMyProfile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyProfile()
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
                return this.Ok(user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error getting user profile");
                return this.Problem(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**My Program.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
             .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
             .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
var scopeRequiredByApi = app.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"] ?? "";
```

**My appsettings.json**

```json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have any update on this question? Pls kindly let me know whether my post help to solve your issue or not.

Comment: I was trying with your code but my fresh auth token got unauthorised. Please help me with new and refresh token generation step.

Comment: I'm glad to see you coming back ... refresh token can only be generated in auth code flow. Just like what I mentioned below, we can only use on-behalf-flow or client credential flow in webapi. You'd better to add more details about how you got unauthorised, maybe some error messages and other related information. Anyway  it's impossible to have refresh token in web api in your case. In the end, if you think others' answsers are helpful, you can vote up them, if your question is resolved by someone, you can click the √ beside it so that it'll help others meeting similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Web API is kind of daemon application which doesn't have a user login UI, so that we can't use it directly for Delegated api permission. We can use On-behalf-of flow for delegated permission and client credential flow for application permission. Here's my sample and test result. Using on-behalf-of flow requires us to use an access token to call the protected web api so that we can add auth to the `_graphServiceClient` we injected in the controller. Therefore, we need to expose api in AAD, more details can be seen [in this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-protected-web-api-overview).

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;

namespace WebApiOnBehalf.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "Tiny.Read")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAsync()
        {
            //using delegated permission
            var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();

            //using application permission
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "tenant_id";
            var clientId = "client_id";
            var clientSecret = "client_secret";
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            var users2 = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  //"Audience": "api://client_id"
},
"Graph": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "Scopes": "user.read"
},
```

[image]
[image]

generate access token using auth code flow which would generate an access token with delegated permission.

[image]

Using this token to call web api which I shared above, the api would validate the access token. Here, the aad app which exposed api and the aad team which being assigned the exposed API is the same app, so that I don't need to identify the audience in appsetting.json. After passing the authorization, the GraphServiceClient would also be authenticated so that we can use it by injecting into controller.